# Effective Java: should I override equals() and hashCode() if the objects I'm creating are never compared with each other?

Tags: java

If the objects I create are not used for comparisons such as `list.contains(new Employee("MM"))`, and also  if those objects will only be stored in `List`s returned from a database such as `List<Employee>employeeList = employeeService.getEmployeeList();` then do I need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Employee` class?

Comment: Any decent IDE (like Eclipse) will generate those for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why overriding Equals Method:**

If you object needs to be stored on Collection i.e List, you should override equals method since when you will use indexOf, lastIndexOf etc API method as those api methods internally uses equals method. If you dont override equal method, then you might get those object back from collections since identity checking is not the right way to get the object back from Collections.

**Why overriding hashCode Method:**

If your object needs to be stored in a set or as key object in a map collection, you must override `HashCode` and `Equals` both becuase both methods are used to get the object back from those collections.

Comment: if I stored Objects in List for only keeping List return from Database,such as  List employeeList = EmployeeService.getEmployeeList()  and I don't use indexOf,lastIndexOf then I need to override equals() and hashcode()?

Comment: if you will never use those API methods which are using equals methods internally, it is not necessary to override equals method.

Comment: Note that you should *never* override just `.equals()` and not `.hashCode()`. If you override one you must override the other, otherwise your objects are broken and you'll very likely run into confusing and difficult to debug issues.

Comment: @dimo414 if you only use List Type collection, it is not required to override hashCode() method, only equal method is okey. But if you want to store Hash... Collection, Map Key, you must override both HashCode and equals.

Comment: @Md.MinhajurRahman,I heard most of develper said if I override equals(),then I should override hashCode().so If I don't override hashCode() as I use only List Type,then it may violating the fact That is "override equals(),need to override hashCode()".is it?

Comment: @Md.MinhajurRahman you don't need to override `.equals()` to use `List`. If you do choose to override `.equals()` and don't override `.hashCode()` you are violating the contract of both methods, and should not expect *anything* to work correctly.

Comment: @dimo414 so it is the best practice

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need to override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` if you don't need a custom definition of equality. As long as you intend to treat every instance of your class as un-equal to other instances the defaults will work fine. You can store such objects in `List`s and even in hash-based collections such as `HashMap`s and `HashSet`s - both classes have no problems with the default `Object` notion of equivalence.

Furthermore for many classes you *shouldn't* override these methods. Many common design patterns will include classes that aren't intended to ever be equivalent, such as [factories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and [state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). Defining a custom notion of equality for such classes can introduce strange bugs, or at a minimum simply be unnecessary boilerplate.

On the other hand [value types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type), or classes intended specifically to be a structured representation of some sort of data should almost always override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` (and possibly implement `Comparable` as well), because it's what users of these sort of classes are likely to expect. The [Auto/Value](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) project makes creating such value types really painless; if that's the type of class you're constructing I'd strongly encourage you to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you will never be using the object as a key in a `HashMap` or will never be putting it in any sort of `Set`, or never doing anything with it where you will do any object comparison other than "are these references referring to literally same instance or not", then you do not have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

And if that's not the case and you do have to override them, then do consider letting your IDE generate the overrides rather than doing it manually -- especially for `hashCode()`.  And be aware that when having the IDE generate these, you can tell the IDE which fields to include and which fields not to include, which even further reduces any need to write the overrides manually.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting objects that don't override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` into a `HashMap` or `HashSet` - as long as identity equivalence is what you expect these collections will handle such objects just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As QuantumMechanic had said above, you do not need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()`.

**However**, if the Employee class is going to be shared with other people, it's a good idea to add equal and hashcode so that it is easier for other people to use.

Also, Eclipse can generate these functions by right clicking -> Source -> Generate `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Good luck!